# MongoDB | update object in array updates different object then given parameters

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

Update query doesn't update the specific object, instead, it updates the object that matches `question` and is the nearest from the start of an array, it doesn't take the `id` parameter it seems like.

Why doesn't it work?

```
console.log({id, question, answer, pollId});

Poll.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: pollId,
    "answers.id": id,
    "answers.question": question,
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "answers.$.answer": answer,
    },
  }
).then((p) => console.log(p.answers.filter((a) => a.id === id)[0]));
```

Console output:

```
//first log
{
  id: '603923508d957f957770c64f',
  question: 0,
  answer: 2,
  pollId: '603ca13cd027bd4b3013e9cc'
}
//second log
{
  id: '603923508d957f957770c64f',
  question: 0,
  answer: 0,
  pollId: '603ca13cd027bd4b3013e9cc'
}
```

Comment: `pollId`, `id` and `question` in the first and second log are the same.

Comment: Yes, I know, because I only update the ```answer``` property of the object. The first log is the desired object and the updated object should look the same, yet it doesn't.

Comment: can we see an example of a before/after document?

Comment: If you are using the `mongoose` library. By default, `findOneAndUpdate()` returns the document as it was before the update was applied. Set `new: true` to get updated data. eg: `findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, {new: true})`

Comment: With { new: true } logged output is the same, sadly.

Comment: Added pictures of db

Answer (score 0):

Images of db during updates

As you can see, it updates the first document in an array, but the update query is not matching the id property.

Query is described in the question.

[before update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwKoL.png)

[after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGU02.png)